# Set the length and/or format of the checksum

Tags: webform-civicrm, sms, checksum

Many of our constituents' online access is limited to a phone, and we get much better response to SMS text messages than to emails. For some contacts, however, clicking on the link in the text message truncates the URL. Likely a phone model issue, but which models is unclear. The issue only shows up in links with checksum, so it may be related to URL length or format (underscores?).

Is there a way to manage the length/format of the checksum? Failing that, where in the code would I look for opportunities to patch the creation and evaluation of checksums?

In case the distinction is important, we use checksums with webform-civicrm in Drupal. We don't use Profiles. Thanks.